# Pass query parameters (from url) through will_paginate to mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, url, parameters, will-paginate

I want to be able pass parameters through the URL to return only the documents that match the search query instead of all the records. How do I get the "prototype" parameter to pass through to the self.all method in my zip.rb file?

Rails s output:

```
Started GET "/?page=2&per_page=200&prototype[state]=NY" for ::1 at 2016-04-03 12:31:58 -0400
Processing by ZipsController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"page"=>"2", "per_page"=>"200", "prototype"=>{"state"=>"NY"}}
paginate({"page"=>"2", "per_page"=>"200", "prototype"=>{"state"=>"NY"}, "controller"=>"zips", "action"=>"index", "sort"=>{}})
getting all zips, prototype={}, sort={}, offset=200, limit=200
```

In the above rails s output, the prototype param is captured in the "Parameters" hash and in paginate, but does not flow to the hash from the self.all method as prototype is blank.

zips_controller.rb

```
def index
 args=params.clone  #update a clone of params
 args[:sort]=get_sort_hash(args[:sort]) #replace sort with hash
 @zips = Zip.paginate(args)
 @locations = zip_markers @zips
end
```

zip.rb

```
def self.all(prototype={}, sort={:population=>1}, offset=0, limit=100)
  #map internal :population term to :pop document term
  tmp = {} #hash needs to stay in stable order provided
  sort.each {|k,v| 
    k = k.to_sym==:population ? :pop : k.to_sym
    tmp[k] = v  if [:city, :state, :pop].include?(k)
  }
  sort=tmp
  #convert to keys and then eliminate any properties not of interest
  prototype.each_with_object({}) {|(k,v), tmp| tmp[k.to_sym] = v; tmp}
  prototype.slice!(:city, :state, :pop) if !prototype.nil?

 Rails.logger.debug {"getting all zips, prototype=#{prototype}, sort=# {sort}, offset=#{offset}, limit=#{limit}"}

 result=collection.find(prototype)
      .projection({_id:true, city:true, state:true, pop:true, loc:true})
      .sort(sort)
      .skip(offset)
 result=result.limit(limit) if !limit.nil?

 return result
end

def self.paginate(params)
  Rails.logger.debug("paginate(#{params})")
  page=(params[:page] ||= 1).to_i
  limit=(params[:per_page] ||= 30).to_i
  offset=(page-1)*limit
  sort=params[:sort] ||= {}

  #get the associated page of Zips -- eagerly convert doc to Zip
  zips=[]
  all(params, sort, offset, limit).each do |doc|
    zips << Zip.new(doc)
 end

 #get a count of all documents in the collection
 total=all(params, sort, 0, 1).count

 WillPaginate::Collection.create(page, limit, total) do |pager|
   pager.replace(zips)
 end    
end
```

Comment: Nevermind - I only needed to pass state="NY" to the url and not prototype with hash keys/values.